# criando um dataframe a partir de pares de colunas em Python

Tags: python, funções, pandas

Utilizando a biblioteca yfinance importei dados de uma lista com 80 ativos:

```
tickers=['xxx','yyy']
data = yf.download(tickers, start="2020-01-01", end="2020-12-04")
data = data['Close']
```

Utilizei uma função e extraí uma lista de pares desses ativos.
Segundo meu critério tenho selecionado 88 pares.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora gostaria de uma função que criasse um dataframe, para posterior exportação para o Excel, onde cada worksheet receberia o nome do par e as cotações de cada ativo organizadas nas colunas B e C, sendo a coluna A reservada para a data.

Comment: Não está claro para mim o que vc está tendo fazer. O que são coluns A, B e C? Como você importou o objeto `yf`?

Comment: yf é a biblioteca do Yahoo Finanace ````import yfinance as yf````      Colunas A, B e C seriam as colunas de saída de cada par(A para data, B para o primeiro ativo do par e C para o segundo ativo do par)